# Executing a function base on a condition

Tags: python, function

I want to execute a function based on a condition. If the `sentence` variable is set to `How are you?`, then I want the `reply()` function to change the value of the `response` to `I am good` so the Bot can respond.
Any help is appreciated.

```
response = ""
def reply():
    response = 'I am good'
    return;

sentence = input('You: ')

if sentence == "How are you?":
    reply()
print('Bot: ' + response)
```

Comment: Why not `return response`? That seems the easiest way to solve the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary for matching replies:

```
reply_dict = {
    "How are you?" : "I am good"
}
sentence = input('You: ')
response = reply_dict.get(sentence, "")
print('Bot: ' + response)
```

Notice the use of `dict.get` method, it will search for the sentence in it and return us the matching value, if not found I set the default value to `""`.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Set response to global

```
response = ""
def reply():
    global response
    response = 'I am good'
    return;

sentence = input('You: ')

if sentence == "How are you?":
    reply()
    global response
print('Bot: ' + response)
```

Comment: wow, really?  I think there are much better options for this, including cleaning up the code there.

Comment: Also, this one doesn't even run. You should declare "global response" before setting it.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @AmitojSingh, its ok, dont be greedy about adquiring points or answering questions, you should always take in account the quality of your answers to help the comunity, it would have been better to explain to him how to return a value from a function and reasignt the variable from that than using the quick solution which is the global...

Comment: @Netwave I am suggesting him what i have learnt so far. As also i am not expert but thing is that atleast i can help someome as i have also passed through these problems when i was begginer.

Comment: @AmitojSingh, this is the stuff that happens when people dont understand what they are doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305190/making-a-function-available-in-another-function